# SharePoint 2013 FBA for partners

Tags: sharepoint, adfs, fba

I  am trying to build a SP2013 FBA for our partners, problem is we have more than 200 partners
and Ideally what I want to achieve is

1)walmart.contoso.com
2)target.contoso.com  and so on

is it recommended to go this route

Questions
1) Do i need a static ip for each of the partners
2)I want to give each partner ways to maintain their own users on the portal
3)Can it be done without ADFS server 
4)are there going to be subsites in a main site collection

any thoughts from experts TIA